# How to add the option to allow only one space in a regex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I want a regex that will allow only one space within a set of characters.
I have the below regex which doesn't accept space.
The below regex only supports strings like

**1. @alia
2. @ranbir
3. @shilpa**

```
const regex = /@(\w+([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[-]|[_]|[.]|['])*)$/g;
```

I want a regex that will allow strings like

**1. @alia bhat
2. @ranbir kapoor
3. @shilpa shetty**

Comment: I don't know anything about regex, but `@(\w+([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[-]|[_]|[.]|['])*)\s?(\w+([a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]|[-]|[_]|[.]|['])*)$`  works (but very inefficient)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
@([\w\-\.\']+(?:\s[\w\-\.\']+)?)$
```

Explanation: group all the chars in a single set (\w = a-zA-Z0-9_ + the rest of the chars)

then a next group would optionally match a single space followed by at least one character of the same set of characters, this means that your current single words will match and also two words but not if there is two spaces or just a single space at the end

Working example:
https://regex101.com/r/czanzG/1

[image]

If you want to allow a single space after the name, then you just remove the \s from the group

```
@([\w\-\.\']+\s?(?:[\w\-\.\']+)?)$
```

https://regex101.com/r/IgROrF/1

[image]

Comment: Nicer than mine... While the apostrophe and dash do not need to be escaped.

Comment: how about allowing a single space after the first name aswell eg:@test

Comment: I purposfuly prevented that cause I thought that "@test" was valid but "@test " was not. I've updated the answer and added at the bottom how you can change it to consider "@test " with a single space at the end as valid, but "@test  " with two spaces at the end is still invalid

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex alternative. First alternative is accepting the space and second is your original regex.

```
/@(\w+ \w+|\w+)/g
```

**Updated**

I forgot to put `$` (regex the end of string) and include some characters `.-'`

```
/@([\w\-.']+ [\w\-.']+|[\w\-.']+)$/g
```

Example : https://regex101.com/r/LT7I1M/1

Comment: The dot and the apostrophe are not word characters.

Comment: This will also match the single first word of two words separated by two spaces